# Matplotlib hangs in Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to draw some charts generated by Matplotlib but I am finding that whilst it works correctly the first time, if I refresh my page, Matplotlib will just hang on `_tkinter.create` deep within its inner workings (Tkinter.py) when creating the figure (`plt.figure`). I've managed to narrow down the issue with the following small example..

Template (Only needs this one line)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graph }}"/>
```

Chart creation

```
class PolarChart(object):    
    @staticmethod
    def example_chart():
        from math import pi, radians
        import cStringIO
        import base64  
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        fig = plt.figure()    
        axis = fig.gca(polar=True)

        n = 20
        theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * pi, n, endpoint=False)
        radii = 10 * np.random.rand(n)

        axis.plot(theta, radii, marker='.', alpha=0.5, linewidth=1)

        jpg_image_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
        fig.savefig(jpg_image_buffer)

        plt.close(fig)
        base_array = base64.b64encode(jpg_image_buffer.getvalue())
        jpg_image_buffer.close()

        return base_array
```

View

```
graph = PolarChart.example_chart()

return render(request, "test.html", {'graph': graph})
```

Other stackoverflow questions have suggested using `fig.clear()` but this also results in the page not rendering (the same hanging effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an issue with using the wrong backend... The issue was resolved with [jenshnielsen's suggestion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4106) to change the backend that is being used before importing `pyplot`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

<sub>If your reading this, Jens, please post your own answer and I'll gladly delete this one!</sub>