# out of stack space (infinite loop?) error while working with matplolib and Django

Tags: html, django, matplotlib

I am trying to show a graph which I am trying to plot in Matplotlib and then showing it with some hard coding in HTML template.But out of 3 attempts, it is working only once else it is throwing  TCL Out of stack space error. Below is my coding.

def similar_images(request):

```
n_groups = 5

means_men = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
std_men = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

means_women = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
std_women = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # somwhere here it is throwing this error 

index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35

opacity = 0.4
error_config = {'ecolor': '0.3'}

rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_men, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 yerr=std_men,
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='Men')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_women, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='r',
                 yerr=std_women,
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='Women')

plt.xlabel('Shoe')
plt.ylabel('Week')
plt.title('Last Year sale details')
#plt.xticks(index + bar_width / 2, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('/graph.png')

plt.close()

return render(request,'sales/Details.html')
```

Please, can someone help me here?

Below is the error.

Exception Type: TclError at /sales/similar_images/
Exception Value: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Comment: Please let me know if any other piece of code is required.

Comment: Which backend are you using? you might want to [try using `agg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28538794/1324033)

Comment: I am using Django here.

Comment: packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py" in new_figure_manager
  81.     return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)

File "/home/affine/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py" in new_figure_manager_given_figure
  89.     window = Tk.Tk()

File "/home/affine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py" in __init__
  1820.         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)

Exception Type: TclError at /sales/similar_images/
Exception Value: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Comment: @Sayse I tried using agg but still, it is giving the same error. Not sure what is causing this issue.